# Multiprocessing Error when Downloading files from FTP

Tags: python, ftp, multiprocessing

I have been stuck on this particular beauty of a code for a while and I can figure out why it isn't working. When I run the code below I get a pickling error and it is always on a different file.

This will download a random number of files and then magically stop. For some reason the ith file name (or wherever it chooses to stop) is suddenly not pickleable whereas the other ones before it were. I could see *all* of them not being pickleable or none of them but having an arbitrary number not be pickleable is just weird.

```
n=10
urls = ["ftp://ftp.sec.gov/{0:s}".format(f) for f in flist[:n]]
print urls
from multiprocessing import Pool
from urllib import urlretrieve

def download(url):
    try:
        file_name = str(url.split('/')[-1])
        print file_name
        return urlretrieve(url, file_name), None
    except Exception as e:
        return None, e

if __name__ == "__main__":
   p = Pool(10) 
   p.map(download, urls)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib64/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 250, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 554, in get
    raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[(('0000950144-94-000788.txt', <mimetools.Message instance at 0x6333878>), None)]'. Reason: 'PicklingError("Can't pickle <type 'cStringIO.StringI'>: attribute lookup cStringIO.StringI failed",)'
```

Does anyone know why the ith element is suddenly not pickleable? Whereas the other ones were before? I can see it is because it thinks the ith name is a stringIO but that makes no sense because the ones before it should have been as well then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a [mimetools.Message](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetools.html#mimetools.Message) object representing the FTP headers.  Either zap it, or turn into an ordinary string before returning it.

Here's an example of the latter:

```
n=10
urls = ["ftp://ftp.sec.gov/{0:s}".format(f) for f in flist[:n]]
print urls
from multiprocessing import Pool
from urllib import urlretrieve

def download(url):
    try:
        file_name = str(url.split('/')[-1])
        print file_name
        filename,headers = urlretrieve(url, file_name)
        return (filename, repr(headers), None
    except Exception as e:
        return None, e

if __name__ == "__main__":
   p = Pool(10) 
   p.map(download, urls)
```

Comment: When I run the above I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'download'

Which is weird because the module had the attribute beforehand..
Also I fixed the syntax error so thats not it.